# Wordpress short-code using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I couldn't find an easy solution to call a php shortcode with javascript. 
I have this javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../wp-content/themes/medical-cure/ads_script.php',
            success: function(data) {

                $("p").text(data);
            }
        });
   });
});
```

Where ads_script.php contains:

```
<?php 
    echo do_shortcode( '[wprevive_js zoneid="10"]' );
?>
```

all executed when I click a button:

```
<button class="button" type="button" >Click Me</button>
```

But all this gives me a 500error.
Maybe I have to ask wordpress stackexchange because

```
do_shortcode( '[wprevive_js zoneid="10"]' );
```

is actually a Worpdress code, but I'd appreciate any help here.

UPDATE:

If I try to put `echo "hi"` instead of the shortcode, it works, return me "HI" when I start the Ajax call with the button.

Comment: "give me 500error."  Check your error logs to find the specific error being thrown and include that above.

Comment: @PatrickQ there is no response or any log, gives me 500 server error at ads_script.php in console

Comment: It would be _highly_ unlikely for there not to be an error logged _somewhere_ with a 500 status response.  Where are you looking?

Comment: @PatrickQ all I can see is from my console, I can't access to server log, so in console I see 500error into jquery.min.js at line 4 "send", "ajax". There is no better explain of this error :(

Comment: "I can't access to server log"  You need to figure out how to get access to your logs.  You really shouldn't be doing any development without it.  We're not going to be able to help you without knowing what the actual error message is.  As a developer, your logs are basically your first line of debugging.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes I will try to get the access, I have worked in javascript only, so the error is always visible into console. that's why :) php gives error server-side so I can't see the full error in console maybe

Comment: @PatrickQ in log there is: `mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function do_shortcode() in /mnt/vhosts/my-wesbite.com/dev/wp-content/themes/medical-cure/ads_script.php:4, referer: https://my-wesbite.com/test/` and `500 POST /wp-content/themes/medical-cure/ads_script.php HTTP/1.0` all I can see from log...

Comment: "undefined function do_shortcode()"  There's your error.  My guess is that the request isn't actually running through WP.  So you likely need to either make the request via a WP route (instead of explicitly calling that file directly), or figure out how to include the WP core on that page.  I can't tell you how to do either of those though, as I detest WP.  Hopefully someone else will come along that can help you.

Comment: @PatrickQ thanks for all bro :)

Comment: Do you have to include any files before you make the do shortcode call?

Comment: @unixmiah  Well yes, because I'm calling an Ajax function that call an external php file

Comment: WordPress has a framework for calling AJAX - https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins. It will load WordPress which is the cause of your problem. echo() works since it doesn't require WordPress. do_shortcode() requires WordPress and cannot work if WordPress is not loaded.

Comment: You do not have to use the framework but if you do not it is your responsibility to load WordPress by requiring wp-load.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've isolated your ads_script.php away from the WordPress core.

Since you're making a direct call to it, it doesn't load WordPress and their gives the do_shortcode not a function error.

Try loading wp_load.php in your ads_script.php file.

It'll look something like:

```
<?php 
 // instead of include '../../../wp-load.php'; do ...
  $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
  require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );

  echo do_shortcode( '[wprevive_js zoneid="10"]' );
?>
```

Comment: yeah exactly my thought

Comment: its worked bro! many thanks! Only instead of `.text(data)` I have put `.html(data)` to show correctly the shortcode.

Comment: first person who solved this issue after days of trying. Thanks again.